# change mongodb field type from int to double

Tags: mongodb

I am using *mongoimport* to import *csv* to *mongodb*. Due to *csv* I can not specify the field type, 0 will be looked at as an int, but I need it be a double. So I tried to write a JavaScript file to do the convert:

```
db.col.find().forEach( function(obj) { obj.n = new double( obj.n ); db.col.save(obj); } )
```

But it report error:

```
Cannot use 'commands' readMode, degrading to 'legacy' mode
2016-04-12T17:08:15.286+0800 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: double is not
defined :
@(shell):1:41
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:477:1
@(shell):1:1
```

I have tried `Double`, `NumberDouble` and `numberDouble` none of them work.

Comment: can you try `obj.n = +obj.n || 0`

Comment: @kiro112 don't work, type still is int32

Comment: try using `parseFloat()` instead of +

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
db  .col
    .find()
    .forEach(function(obj) { 
        obj.n = parseFloat(obj.n) || 0;
        db.col.save(obj);
    });
```

Comment: don't work. I remember if the value is unchanged, the $set will not work

Comment: @jean try the edit. working on mongo 3.0.11

Comment: don't work. I even try: obj.n = Number(0.0); still Int32